# Register global hotkey for copy

Tags: c#, wpf, global, copy-paste, registerhotkey

I need help with that problem:

I tried to register a hotkey (Ctrl+Shift+C) which works global (also in other applications). When it is pressed it should get me the selected object (String, File, ... it's not defined here). The applicaions should be a WPF-Project.

I found some code-parts but at the end it hadn't worked.

What I try to do with? I try to make a clipboard helping tool where I can store multiple items

Lots of thank

Damon

---

**The Code for Hotkey**

```
public sealed class HotKey : IDisposable
{
    public event Action<HotKey> HotKeyPressed;

    private readonly int _id;
    private bool _isKeyRegistered;
    readonly IntPtr _handle;

    public HotKey(ModifierKeys modifierKeys, System.Windows.Forms.Keys key, System.Windows.Window window)
        : this(modifierKeys, key, new WindowInteropHelper(window))
    {
        Contract.Requires(window != null);
    }

    public HotKey(ModifierKeys modifierKeys, System.Windows.Forms.Keys key, WindowInteropHelper window)
        : this(modifierKeys, key, window.Handle)
    {
        Contract.Requires(window != null);
    }

    public HotKey(ModifierKeys modifierKeys, System.Windows.Forms.Keys key, IntPtr windowHandle)
    {
        Contract.Requires(modifierKeys != ModifierKeys.None || key != System.Windows.Forms.Keys.None);
        Contract.Requires(windowHandle != IntPtr.Zero);

        Key = key;
        KeyModifier = modifierKeys;
        _id = GetHashCode();
        _handle = windowHandle;
        RegisterHotKey();
        ComponentDispatcher.ThreadPreprocessMessage += ThreadPreprocessMessageMethod;
    }

    ~HotKey()
    {
        Dispose();
    }

    public System.Windows.Forms.Keys Key { get; private set; }

    public ModifierKeys KeyModifier { get; private set; }

    public void RegisterHotKey()
    {
        if (Key == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.None)
            return;
        if (_isKeyRegistered)
            UnregisterHotKey();
        _isKeyRegistered = HotKeyWinApi.RegisterHotKey(_handle, _id, KeyModifier, Key);
        if (!_isKeyRegistered)
            throw new ApplicationException("Hotkey already in use");
    }

    public void UnregisterHotKey()
    {
        _isKeyRegistered = !HotKeyWinApi.UnregisterHotKey(_handle, _id);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ComponentDispatcher.ThreadPreprocessMessage -= ThreadPreprocessMessageMethod;
        UnregisterHotKey();
    }

    private void ThreadPreprocessMessageMethod(ref MSG msg, ref bool handled)
    {
        if (!handled)
        {
            if (msg.message == HotKeyWinApi.WmHotKey
                && (int)(msg.wParam) == _id)
            {
                OnHotKeyPressed();
                handled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnHotKeyPressed()
    {
        if (HotKeyPressed != null)
            HotKeyPressed(this);
    }
}

internal class HotKeyWinApi
{
    public const int WmHotKey = 0x0312;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, ModifierKeys fsModifiers, System.Windows.Forms.Keys vk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);
}
```

The Main application

```
    private HotKey _hotkey;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += (s, e) =>
        {
            _hotkey = new HotKey(ModifierKeys.Control | ModifierKeys.Shift, System.Windows.Forms.Keys.C, this);
            _hotkey.HotKeyPressed += (k) => DoIt();
        };


    }

    public static void DoIt()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("HotKey pressed!");
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried  using `KeyBinding`?

Comment: Thanks for you fast answer. I tried it but it dont worked :/

Comment: Can you post the code which you tried and didn't worked?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this blog post: [Installing a global hot key with C#](http://www.liensberger.it/web/blog/?p=207)

As for getting the selected text, the code you found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1dc356e6-9441-44de-9eda-247003fa6ef5/copy-selected-text-from-any-window?forum=winformsapplications) is missing the EM_GETSEL message for getting the selection boundaries. You can add the following to the code, and it should work:

```
        //Get the text of a control with its handle
        private string GetText(IntPtr handle)
        {
            int maxLength = 100;
            IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((maxLength + 1) * 2);
            SendMessageW(handle, WM_GETTEXT, maxLength, buffer);
            int selectionStart = -1;
            int selectionEnd = -1;
            SendMessage(handle, EM_GETSEL, out selectionStart, out selectionEnd);
            string w = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(buffer);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
            if (selectionStart > 0 && selectionEnd >0)
            {
                w = w.Substring(selectionStart, selectionEnd - selectionStart); //We need to send the length
            }
            return w;
        }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, out int wParam, out int lParam);

    public const uint EM_GETSEL = 0xB0;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! The hotkey is not the "real" problem. I've already made a function hotkey but in Connection with the marked object is the problem... If the hotkey is activated how do i get the selected object? (This 2 things together is my problem ^^)

I hope you understand what I mean (with my bad english XD)

Comment: It works now o.O... But not 100% correctly... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1dc356e6-9441-44de-9eda-247003fa6ef5/copy-selected-text-from-any-window?forum=winformsapplications I tried this but how do i get only the selected text instead of the whole text?

Comment: The code at your link is missing the EM_GETSEL message to get the selection boundaries.

Comment: See my updated answer for a way of incorporating EM_GETSEL into your code.